# Count and show substring of request URI in Kibana diagram

Tags: logstash, kibana

I'm trying to get a pie diagram based on my apache access log. I want to display which context is called how many times.

Let's say I have a couple of request URIs like

```
/de/some/german/page
/en/some/english/page
/en/the/next/english/page
/ApplicationContext/path/within/application
/en/and/yet/another/english/page
```

Based on those information I'd like to get a diagram or table that states

```
de = 1 hit
en = 3 hits
ApplicationContext = 1 hit
```

Is there a way to extract the context from the request URI and count those substrings? I'd prefere to solve this problem in kibana but if I can only achieve this by adding some filter grok oder regex filter to my logstash config I'd do that as well. But therefore I need a push in the right direction as well;-)

Thanks and regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

As you predicted, this is best done in logstash.  A pattern like this run against the request URI should do the trick:

> /%{WORD:path1}/